# Cannot convert from Plugin.InAppBilling.ItemType to bool

Tags: xamarin.forms, nuget-package, in-app-billing

I use the InAppBilling plugin from the author jamesmontemagno version 4.x. (last stable)

Follow the code return error: Cannot convert from 'Plugin.InAppBilling.ItemType' to 'bool'

Original [example Method](https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/InAppBillingPlugin/GetProductDetails.html) by jamesmontemagno

```
var connected = await billing.ConnectAsync(ItemType.InAppPurchase);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the [docs](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin#upgrading-from-23-to-4) clearly note

> Change: await
> CrossInAppBilling.Current.ConnectAsync(ItemType.InAppPurchase); to
> await CrossInAppBilling.Current.ConnectAsync();